# Android studio: same filename inside both androidTest and test folders

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a java test file with same name `FooTest.java` inside both `androidTest` and `test` folders.

Watching the gradle properties of the build I see that their source sets point to separate folders:

```
build.gradle name: android.sourceSets.androidTest
Java sources: [app/src/androidTest/java]

build.gradle name: android.sourceSets.test
Java sources: [app/src/test/java]
```

However Android Studio (2.1.2) complains about duplicate class being present (Duplicate class found in the file '..').

Does it have a fix?

Thanks.